# Tensorflow TimeoutError connection attempt failed

Tags: tensorflow

Source Code: https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_demo

Video Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FmcHiLCwTU

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe     C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/tensorflow_demo-master/tensorflow_demo-master/board.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1254, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1106, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 877, in send
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 849, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
raise err
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/tensorflow_demo-master/tensorflow_demo-master/board.py", line 3, in <module>
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\tensorflow_demo-master\tensorflow_demo-master\input_data.py", line 149, in read_data_sets
local_file = maybe_download(TRAIN_IMAGES, train_dir)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\tensorflow_demo-master\tensorflow_demo-master\input_data.py", line 17, in maybe_download
filepath, _ = urlretrieve(SOURCE_URL + filename, filepath)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 188, in urlretrieve
with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 163, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 466, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 484, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1282, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1256, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I installed Tensorflow on Windows using Python 3.5.2; When I try to run the board.py file I get a timeout error. I get this error on a number of tensorflow scripts I tried to run. Whats causing this error and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The MNIST dataset, hosted at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/, appears to be offline currently. Unfortunately, that URL seems to be hard-coded in the various example files, but you could try changing it to one of the mirrors listed in this [pull request](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/pull/589/files):

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150912040653/http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/lasagne/recipes/datasets/mnist/

Note that you can download the files manually to the temporary directory specified in the `input_data.read_data_sets()` call (in your case, this appears to be `/tmp/data/`). If the reader code finds the files in that location, it will not attempt to contact the server.